# Pay users Paypal from admin Paypal, without Website interaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on Ruby on Rails
I need to pay some set of user through paypal.
How can i do, There should not be any redirection to webview.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) can do that for you.  You'll need to be doing an implicit approval with your own account as the payer, or if 3rd party users will be paying they will need to setup a [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/).

Then you can make Pay calls to submit payments without further approval (so no redirect required).